# Create a radial gradient stroke around a circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to create a radial gradient stroke around a circle,something similar to
[image]

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/E58K3/5/) is what I've tried so far,

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("analog-stopwatch");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cx=200, cy=200, radius=100;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
// I want the ring width to be 20
var radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, radius, cx, cy, radius+20);
radialGradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
radialGradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");
//context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = radialGradient;
context.stroke();
```

One way I could think of is creating a circle with radial gradient & clipping it with a concurrent circle of lesser radius, but is there any simpler way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler way: draw the outer circle in one direction (ex:clockwise), then draw the inner circle with the other : it will be subtracted from the first path.
Then fill the resulting path :

[image]

fiddle : 
http://jsbin.com/UCiCaYOn/1/edit?js,output

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("analog-stopwatch");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var cx=200, cy=200, radius=100;
context.beginPath();
// !!!!
context.arc(cx, cy, radius+30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false); // !!!
context.arc(cx, cy, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);  // !!!
// !!!!
var radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, radius, cx, cy, radius+20);
radialGradient.addColorStop(0, "black");
radialGradient.addColorStop(1, "blue");
context.fillStyle = radialGradient;
context.fill();
context.closePath();
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically all you need to do is to change the rectangle a bit for the gradient and you're good (no need to stroke two arcs etc.):

```
var lineWidth = 20;
var radialGradient = context.createRadialGradient(cx, cy, radius-lineWidth*0.5,
                                                  cx, cy, radius+lineWidth*0.5);
```

Now you can stroke:

**[Updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/E58K3/6/)**

[image]

Comment: I've one doubt, the above technique is decreasing the diameter of circle by "lineWidth", so I updated the gradient such that inner circle radius is "radius" & outer circle radius as "radius + lineWidth", still it is decreasing the diameter by same amount, any idea why ? Here is the fiddle with what I've explained http://jsfiddle.net/E58K3/8/

Comment: @Unspecified a stroke is always draw centered on the arc path. Just subtract 50% of the width of the line-width to get the outer boundary of the circle equal the intended diameter. This technique here is faster as it draws only one arc.